# How to read a file with numbers on each line in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a file that contains 10 numbers then adding them to an array so I can sort them later on but I'm having trouble reading them in. Not sure why this isn't working for me, can someone explain what is wrong? There's only a number on each lines.

```
10.05
11.01
9.03
```

```
    double nums[10] = {0};
    int count;

    if ((fptr = fopen("filename", "r")) == NULL){
            printf("Error opening file.\n");
    }

    while ((c = getc(fptr)) != EOF){
            if (c != '\n'){
                    nums[count] = (double)c;
                    count = count + 1;
            }
    }
    fclose(fptr);
```

Comment: is `fscanf()` banned?

Comment: `c` is just one character. What do you expect `(double)c` to do?

Comment: 10.05 is not an integer!

Comment: No but I thought you needed to know the exact numbers in the file to use 'fscanf()'? The file will be appending new numbers and sorting them with the max numbers being 10 so there wont always be a set amount in there.

Comment: I added the '(double)c' in to convert it, maybe? Not sure, as you can tell I'm still new.

Comment: `printf("Error opening file.\n");` - After this you cannot continue

Comment: Why not `while (count < 10 && fscanf (fptr, "%lf", &nums[count]) == 1) count++;` ?? (you must initialize `int count = 0;` up top - as shown it is *uninitialized* before its first use in your code -- which invokes *Undefined Behavior*)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank you this worked!!!

Comment: You are welcome. If you needed to use `getc()`, then @MikeCAT provides a good example. Make sure you correct the issue Ed Heal has pointed out. Adding a `return 1;` below `printf("Error opening file.\n");` will do.

Comment: When I see a cast - something is wrong

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong:

- You are storing only one character.
- You are updating `count` each times on non-newline characters while updating should be on newline characters.
- `count` is used without being initialized.
- Casting to `double` is not for this usage.

Possible fix:

```
int c;
FILE* fptr;

char line[1024]; // add line buffer and size tracking
int lineCount = 0;
double nums[10] = {0};
int count = 0; // initialize count

if ((fptr = fopen("filename", "r")) == NULL){
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
} else { // avoid using NULL to read file

    while ((c = getc(fptr)) != EOF){
            if (c == '\n'){ // update nums on newline character
                    line[lineCount] = '\0'; // don't forget to terminate the string
                    nums[count] = atof(line); // atof() from stdlib.h is useful to convert string to number
                    count = count + 1;
                    lineCount = 0; // start to read next line
            } else { // read line contents
                line[lineCount] = (char)c;
                lineCount = lineCount + 1;
            }
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Comment: `printf("Error opening file.\n");` - After this you cannot continue

Comment: And... what if the file has 10,000 values in it? May also want to comment that `atof()` provides zero diagnostics of a failed conversion. `atof ("my cow");` will happily return `0` without any warning. (better with `sscanf` or `strtod`)

Answer (score 0):

Here I go

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   double values[10];
   int count;
   FILE *f = fopen("filename", "r");
   if (f == NULL)| {
      fprintf(stderr, "Some error message");
      return EXIT_FAILURE; // We cannot go any further - file is dead
   }
   // This is basic - you could overcome error problems
   // When able to read (including white space) we carry on until the array is full
   //  This is an area for improvement - error checking etc. 
   for (count = 0;  count < 10 && fscanf(f, " %lf", &values[count]) != 1; count ++);
   fclose(f);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```